# Excel: Doing calculations based on grouped data in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a small problem in a PivotTable: I have a large Table in which every entry has a date. In the PivotTable I have grouped those entries by month. So far so good, but now when I add calculations the results are derived from the original ungrouped data and not the accumulated monthly values.

I have for example calculated the mean, maximum and minimum values and I want to have the the biggest, smallest, etc. *monthly* value however I get the biggest and smallest entry of the data in the original table.

How I can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657393/use-formula-in-custom-calculated-field-in-pivot-table) answer. So calculate your requirements in the source data instead. There is information about MAX IF [here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excel2010functions/qt/2010-04-26-excel-2010-max-function.htm).