# Computed field on pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, computed-field

here there is my table

```
N   tag
1   7-3
2   3-4
3   2-4
4   5-3
5   4-6
6   3-1
7   3-1
8   3-4
9   5-6
```

I need to create a Pivot Table (I do not know how many rows there will be) with the first value of Tag. 
Example :

```
B2="7-3"  ---> =VALUE(LEFT(B2;FIND( "-";B2 ) - 1 )) = 7
```

So the expected table should be:

```
N   FirstTag
1   7
2   3
3   2
4   5
5   4
6   3
7   3
8   3
9   5
```

When I create the computed field for the pivot table I get error:
[image]

Can you help me?
Riccardo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to all of the normal functions in a `Calculated Field`. Check out [this previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657393/use-formula-in-custom-calculated-field-in-pivot-table) about the topic.  It looks like you may only have access to `SUM`.  *I have not confirmed that though.*

I would recommend creating a `Table` with the formula added as a column formula.  This allows it to apply to all of the rows that you don't know exist yet.  You can then summarize the `Table` with a Pivot Table and the `Data Source` will expand/contract as needed.

**Picture of resulting table and Pivot**, not sure what the Pivot is for so I just put the fields in a hierarchy.

[image: picture]

**Formula in `FIRST TAG`**

```
=VALUE(LEFT([@TAG],FIND( "-",[@TAG] ) - 1 ))
```

Comment: I do not understand how you created the First Tag. What @TAG is?. When I try in my Excel I get an error

Comment: You have to create a `Table` out of the data first.  Use CTRL+T or `Insert->Table`.  From there the columns will be named and you can use those names in the formulas.

Comment: Got it! However when you created the table you selected just few rows. If you don't know the number or rows? Is it possible to modify the formula in order to be computed just for the rows where TAG is set?

Comment: You could wrap the formula in a `IF([@TAG]<>"", ..., "")`, but the real question is: how is the data going to be put into this worksheet?  I assume you are copy/pasting from somewhere else which makes the `Table` ideal since it will expand with more data.

Comment: The excel sheet is filled by a software tool. Let's consider the excel like a template file. The software runs and fills the table. The user opens the file and looks at the pivot. The software knows the number of rows but it just fills the column TAG and not FirstTag

Comment: Really depends on the "software".  If it is filled using the Excel object model, the `Table` will automatically expand as the values are added.  If you are just creating an `.xlsx` file using other libraries, then you will probably do better to count rows and add the formula explicitly.  That's really a different problem than this one though.

Answer (score 0):

The PT example you show has a row for `(blank)` so if you don’t mind that, or are happy enough with filtering out that row, I’d not worry about not knowing how many rows of data you may receive – merely pivot entire columns.

Then it is really just a question of how to get from `n-m` to `n` format. Options for which include:

1. a formula that extracts up to but not including the hyphen
   (yours and @Byron’s approach)
2. Text to Columns with `-` as the delimiter (the right-hand column
   then ignorable)

   and, my preference
3. Find what: `-*`, Replace with nothing.

Refresh the PT when new data is imported.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using a formula. However I do not like that I need to know the max number of rows where the formula should be computed..

Comment: I was trying to compute the formula as computed field. I understood that there is an Excel restriction..