# Using a pivot table's calculated field to sum up conditional values

Tags: excel, pivot-table, calculated-field, custom-function

I have the following data set:

```
+--------+---------+----------+
|  Date  | Revenue | Expected |
+--------+---------+----------+
| Dez 5  |      51 |        1 |
| Dez 4  |      72 |        1 |
| Dez 3  |      72 |        1 |
| Dez 2  |      59 |        1 |
| Dez 1  |      81 |        1 |
| Nov 30 |      50 |        1 |
| Nov 29 |      53 |        1 |
| Nov 28 |      99 |        0 |
| Nov 27 |      85 |        0 |
| Nov 26 |      65 |        0 |
| Nov 25 |      94 |        0 |
+--------+---------+----------+
```

The column `Expected` determines whether or not the `Revenue` number has been confirmed. Now, I want to have a pivot table that sums up the revenues per month. The final result should be this:

```
+-------+-------------------+-----+
| Month |                   |     |
+-------+-------------------+-----+
| Nov   | Revenues          | 446 |
|       | Expected Revenues | 103 |
| Dez   | Revenues          | 335 |
|       | Expected Revenues | 335 |
+-------+-------------------+-----+
```

I can't seem to get this working for the month November, because my calculated field looks like this:

```
=IF(Expected*1>0;Revenues*1;0)
```

I had to add `*1` because it wouldn't work for some numbers, so you can mentally ignore this for the moment.

In any case, the result of this is the following:

```
+-------+-------------------+-----+
| Month |                   |     |
+-------+-------------------+-----+
| Nov   | Revenues          | 446 |
|       | Expected Revenues | 446 |
| Dez   | Revenues          | 335 |
|       | Expected Revenues | 335 |
+-------+-------------------+-----+
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? I understand that the reason for this is most likely that the Expected column gets summed up first and then the IF comparison comes about. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: For the problem you describe, the simplest solution is to add a column to your original data set.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657393/use-formula-in-custom-calculated-field-in-pivot-table/16660295#16660295) provides a good summary of the challenges, and confirms your understanding of summing happening first.